# Count daily rows by tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have a database with ~200 tables that I want to audit to ensure the tables won't grow too large.

I know I can easily get an idea of a lot of the table attributes I want (size in MB, rows, row length, data length, etc) with:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM myDatabaseName;
```

But it's missing one key piece of information I'm after: **how many rows are added to each table in a given time period?**

My records each contain a `datestamp` column in matching formats, if it helps.

Edit: Essentially, I want something like:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM * 
 WHERE datestamp BETWEEN [begindate] AND [enddate] 
 GROUP BY tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work to get number of rows entered in for a given table for a given time period:

```
select count(*) from [tablename] where datestamp between [begindate] and [enddate]
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is the ability to run this for _every_ table, something like: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM * WHERE datestamp BETWEEN [begindate] AND [enddate] GROUP BY tablename`

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, it looks like this isn't possible in MySQL, since it would require massive table reads (after all, the number of rows can differ between users).

Instead, I grabbed the transaction logs for all the jobs that write into the tables and I'll parse them. A bit hacky, but it works.